# Fetching a model/object to use in a partialview in .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, view

I'm writing a .Net Core application and I have a pretty good grip on it after starting about 3 weeks ago.

I have access to an online database using the Entity Framework (EF). I have 4 controllers controlling 4 different type of view categories (each category containing 5 views (index, delete, create, edit and details)). Each of the controllers are creating a PaginatedList in their index method holding either of the 4 model types that I have in my program. This is used to sort the items in the list based on different properties.

## PaginatedList.cs

```
public class PaginatedList<T> : List<T>
{
    public int PageIndex { get; private set; }
    public int TotalPages { get; private set; }

    public PaginatedList(List<T> items, int count, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
    {
        PageIndex = pageIndex;
        TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(count / (double)pageSize);

        this.AddRange(items);
    }

    public bool HasPreviousPage
    {
        get
        {
            return (PageIndex > 1);
        }
    }

    public bool HasNextPage
    {
        get
        {
            return (PageIndex < TotalPages);
        }
    }

    public static async Task<PaginatedList<T>> CreateAsync(IQueryable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
    {
        var count = await source.CountAsync();
        var items = await source.Skip((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToListAsync();
        return new PaginatedList<T>(items, count, pageIndex, pageSize);
    }
}
```

The idea about the PaginatedList is that my database will grow in time and I want to limit how many items that are shown.

I have implemented a small piece of code that marks a selected item in my table with the class "success". Once this happens I want to grab the item that was "selected" and pass that to a PartialView so that I can show its properties, but due to using the PaginatedList as the model I am having a hard time accessing the item I want. I was hoping someone in here might have a solution to this?

The following part is where I try to pass my user to my PartialView:

## UserController index method

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(
        int? page,
        int? id)
{

    ....

    if (id != null)
    {
        ViewData["UserID"] = id.Value;
    } 

    ....

    var users = from u in _context.Users select u;

    return View(await PaginatedList<User>.CreateAsync(users.AsNoTracking(), page ?? 1, pageSize));
}
```

## User Index.cshtml

```
@model PaginatedList<Project.Models.User>

....

@if (itemSelected) //true if item is selected - false otherwise.
{
    int elementID = (int)ViewData["ElementID"];
    <h4>@elementID</h4> //this return the id of the item that was selected

    //var user = Model.ElementAt<User>(elementID); //This is causing me trouble.

    @Html.Partial("PartialUserDetails", user)
}
```

The PaginatedList is the "Model" in the above piece of code, as previously mentioned, so either I have to add my DbContext to that (don't know if possible) and using the `elementID` I should fetch the user or I have to come up with a different way of fetching users. The PaginatedList is though able to sort my items based on different criteria, so the items don't appear in an cronological fashion. E.g.

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

but rather

```
2, 1, 5, 4, 3
```

I was hoping someone in here might have a solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution after googling like an insane and reaching the darkest and deepest corners of the internet. Well not really, but the following line seems to be my savior:

```
var user = Model.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserID == elementID);
```